# Sorting a dict by value in descending order of utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this: `{'ex1': 3, 'ex2': 4, 'ex3': 3}` and I would like to sort it by values. So I do this: `results = sorted(results.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`. I put `reverse=True` because I want it to sort in descending order.
so the code is something like this:

```py
results  = {'ex1': 3, 'ex2': 4, 'ex3': 3}
results = sorted(results.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for item in results:
    print (item[0])
```

and the output is:

```
ex2
ex1
ex3
```

But the output I want is supposed to be look like this:

```
ex2
ex3
ex1
```

because in utf-8, ex3 is greater than ex1.
Actually what I want to say is that, when two keys have even values, I want to print them in descending order.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advanced for your answer

Comment: you told it to sort on the number only, and not consider anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work - the key function can return a tuple:

```
results  = {'ex1': 3, 'ex2': 4, 'ex3': 3}
results = sorted(results.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]), reverse=True)
for item in results:
    print (item[0])
```

Gives output:

```
ex2
ex3
ex1
```